# Load a component specified as url query param in an Angular app hosted in AWS S3

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a Angular app hosted on an AWS S3 bucket, let's call it ***myBucket***. As far as I understand, this means that I can access the app using only the url `http:\\myBucket`. If I try anything like `http:\\myBucket\myPage` it fails.

My app is using `router-outlet` to navigate through pages.

To overcome the fact that I can not use an url like `http:\\myBucket\myPage`, I would like to pass a parameter in the url so that i can guide which is the first Component to be shown in the `router-outlet`. For instance `http:\\myBucket\?nextPage='myPage'` would load the route marked 'myPage' in the `router` configuration.

To do so, in `AppComponent` I have written the following logic

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams
    .subscribe(
      params => {
        console.log('params', params);
        if (params.nextPage) {
          this.router.navigate([params.nextPage]);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['defaultPage']);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Unfortunately, if I do so, I always end into the default page, since `activatedRoute.queryParams` emits always an empty object at first, which leads me to `defaultPage`. When I land to `defaultPage` it is too late to drive my app to whatever is he content of `nextPage` parameter.

Is it possible to find a way to load a page/component specified as url query param?

Comment: If `http:\\myBucket` works, then `http:\\myBucket\myPag` should work also, provided that there is an object by the name `myPag` which is publicly accessible

Comment: Mine is an Angular app, so there is not a `myPage` object

Comment: i have an Angular6 app as my homepage also (www.akberiqbal.com) but when i do akberiqbal.com/about i get the about page from s3 bucket and so on an so forth... you don't need router to go through other pages of your s3 hosted site

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have encountered a "feature" of Angular Router which prevents me to be able to do what i want (see this [issue log](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12157)). Basically it is not possible to decide what to do depending on the presence or not of a query parameter when the app is launched.

So eventually, ngOnInit of AppComponent, I have hacked something like this to go to the page I want to reach in case of absence of query parameters

```
 ngOnInit() {
    // start of hack
    const href = window.location.href;
    const queryParamIndex = href.indexOf('?');
    if (queryParamIndex === -1) {
      this.router.navigate(['defaultPage']);
    }
    // end of hack

    this.route.queryParamMap
      .pipe(
        // the first value emitted is always {} - see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12157
        skip(1),
        // take only the first one to avoid considering the empty objects that
        // the activatedRoute emits when it navigates to other routes
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe(
        paramMap => {
          this.router.navigate([paramMap.get('nextPage)]);
        }
      );
  }
```